# Minimize button of Firefox closes the window

Tags: 20.04, firefox, minimize

Why does the minimize button on Ubuntu 20.04 close Firefox window? Similar questions didn't solve my problem. The favorites bar just reopens Firefox with a new session.

Comment: The minimize button on any open window closes the window and I am unable to restore it. It must be reopened and navigated to where I was before minimizing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. It's the "Click here to hide all windows and show the desktop". You'll find it in the lower left corner with the folder icon.

Click on it and it hides the window and reveals the desktop, click on it again and the window you were working on reappears as it was before hiding.

I don't ken why they wold have a minimize button.

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon as this only works for one minimized window. If you minimize more ir only works on last one. I will continue to work on solving all.

Comment: I do not recognize what you describe. Are you using the standard Ubuntu desktop?